# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in .NET 6.0 - Change builtin document property

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation

Using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document interface in C# you can get/set the document's built-in properties (Author, Title, Subject, Creation date,...) with this code:

```
dynamic docprops = document.BuiltInDocumentProperties;

dynamic prop = docprops[WdBuiltInPropertyEnum];

prop.Value = VALUE;

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(prop);

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(docprops);
```

which works fine if the VALUE is string. When the value is the `System.DateTime`, the `prop.Value` (for example `WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyTimeLastPrinted`) is set to a new value, but when I read the same property again like

```
dynamic docprops = document.BuiltInDocumentProperties;

dynamic prop = docprops[WdBuiltInPropertyEnum];

VALUE = prop.Value;
```

the `VALUE` returns unchanged date. Any idea why the property of type date is not updated?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried to save the document after setting all property values? Do you get the updated values after?

Comment: I have. It preserves the original date. No changes.

Comment: Can you show the complete code with a built-in property name and save statement?